# Problems with setting custom adapter for gridview and getting desired ouput

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, gridview

So I followed a tutorial in setting up a custom `adapter` for a `GridView`, had to change a few things because it wasn't working with my code. No errors, but my output is incorrect. My images and text are all loading onto one spot and not into the pre-set `GridView` layout desired. I am using three `Fragments` because of a tab/swipe layout running from the mainactivity. Really, i m having troubles modifying the tutorial to work with my current `fragments`. Any suggestions?

```
Fragment class/activity:

`public class BankingFrag extends Fragment  {
    GridView gv;

    public static String[] selections = {"Statements, Transfer, E-Transfer, Picture-Deposit "};
    public static int[] imgs = {R.drawable.ic_description_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_swap_horiz_black_24dp
                            , R.drawable.ic_email_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_black_24dp};

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container
            , @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_banking, container, false);
        gv = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gv.setAdapter(new CustomImageAdapter(v.getContext(),selections,imgs));


        return v;
    }


}`

fragment_banking.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/CHQ"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
           />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4,302.98"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/chqText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/SAV"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10,002.56"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/savText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

        <GridView android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="80dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

gridview_item.xml: 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- the parent view -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <!-- the ImageView for the icon -->
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <!--  the TextView for the title -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/opTitle"
        android:layout_below="@id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
</RelativeLayout>

The custom adapter class, CustomImageAdpater.java

    package com.comp3717lab.matt.bankingapp;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String [] result;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomImageAdapter(Context c, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=c;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView text;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
        holder.text=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.opTitle);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);

        holder.text.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}

Thanks for any help! PS new at android dev
```

Comment: do you mean `holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);` this is loading images at one spot? Also instead of null pass parent in `rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);`

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few problems in you `getView` method:

The cells should be recycled and you shouldn't initialize `Holder holder=new Holder();`

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{       
  if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent,
                false);
       //It's a new view so update the data you need
  }
  else //It's a recycled view, so get a reference to it and update the data
  {
     //For example
     (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.opTitle).setText("some text");

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up changing the whole thing, as you suggested I changed the naming to make it more conventional